# Cassandra table design for user chat

Tags: database, database-design, cassandra, nosql

I want to create table in Cassandra for user chats, I end up doing this

```
CREATE TABLE sample.user_messages (
    user_id INT,
    second_user_id INT,
    id TIMEUUID,
    author_id INT,
    message TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY ((user_id), second_user_id, id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (second_user_id ASC, id DESC);
```

I have two type of query

1. get chats between two users that this table design satisfy `... where user_id=100 and second_user_id=200`
2. **get all chats of a specific user that this table design not good for** and I don't have any idea what to do, for this should I use two queries, 1- `... where user_id=100'` 2- ... `where second_user_id=100` which second query is not good, also is there any way where I can use only one query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your table allows you to get all chats by user_id, so you can just insert data twice into this table but change user's ids for the second insert.

Put message for the first user:

```
UPDATE user_messages SET .... second_user_id = 200 WHERE user_id = 100;
```

and put the same message for the second user:

```
UPDATE user_messages SET .... second_user_id = 100 WHERE user_id = 200;
```

Now you can get all chats for each user:

```
Select * from user_messages where user_id = 100;
Select * from user_messages where user_id = 200;
```

Get chat between two users:

```
Select * from user_messages where user_id = 100 and second_user_id = 200;
```

or vice versa:

```
Select * from user_messages where user_id = 200 and second_user_id = 100;
```

This approach will duplicate data but for Cassandra it is a common way to pay for read speed.

**[Edited]** Large partitions issue

If you expect too many messages per user you should choose another partition key rather user_id. For example, you can use a composite partition key which will consist of user_id and day, in this case each partition will contain messages only for one day, but you will have separate partition for each day. This technique is usually called "bucketing", [some example of bucketing](http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2017/08/02/time-series-data-modeling-massive-scale.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I search a bit and found your solution is good one, what if I want to store billions of data, it requires duplicate space and... is it the only solution??

Comment: In Cassandra you should care about partition size only, due to single partition can  not be splitted and placed on different nodes, but different partitions will be spreaded over the cluster. So in your case messages for differnt users will be spreaded on the cluster, but potentially you can have too large partition , if to many messages will be present for one user. I updated my answer for large partition issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two record for both users with inverted ids :

Record 1 : user_id = 1 and second_user_id = 2

Record 2 : user_id = 2 and second_user_id = 1

Obviously, both records must same `id`, `author_id` and `message`

So your second query works

```
SELECT * FROM sample.user_messages WHERE user_id = 1
```

Also your first query may work in all cases because no matter the order of ids you provide in the query :

```
SELECT * FROM sample.user_messages WHERE user_id = 1 AND second_user_id = 2
SELECT * FROM sample.user_messages WHERE user_id = 1 AND second_user_id = 2
```

Both queries will provide the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use secondary Indexing on second_user_id like below:

CREATE INDEX index_second_user_id ON sample.user_messages (second_user_id);

So now your 1st query will remain same.

And your second query will split in 2 separate query on user_id and second_user_id like below

```
1) select * from "user_messages" where user_id=100;
2) select * from "user_messages" where second_user_id=100;
```

This should be helpful.

Comment: I would discourage this design since C* secondary indexes do not work well when you have high key cardinality as each replica keeps its own local index.  If you have high key cardinality, its likely every query would need to hit every replica set which is expensive.  reference: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useWhenIndex.html#useWhenIndex__highCardCol